# Can you view Klockwork's On-The-Fly parser errors?

Tags: visual-studio, klocwork

I'm getting an error in Klocwork's Visual Studio integration stating that

> On-The-Fly analysis did not start due to XX parser errors.

Is there a way to view On-The-Fly parser errors?

The Visual Studio solution is still building successfully, so I'm guessing it's something I need to make Klocwork aware of in the normal build process.

Answer (score 0):

As of Klocwork Insight 10 the Visual Studio plugin will now display any parse errors in the Visual Studio Error List window.

In the previous versions, to view the parse errors you could look through the KWVS.log file which is written by the plugin to the user's temp folder, ie. the value of %TEMP%.

In general, the Klocwork parser is a bit more strict about things like missing semi-colons, etc. than the Visual Studio compiler is.